# Webpage decomposition at load

Tags: html, css, performance, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions

I build a webpage https://dev.dineandgift.com/voucher/108 and on load, I get in 1 second decomposition screen like:

[image]

after a few seconds everything is fine... but this looks very bad. How I can solve this problem? **Why page is a breakdown?**

ANy css, html trick to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both order and placement of your `<link>` (CSS) and `<script>` (Javascript) tags is is way off. That's causing these shifts in page rendering - stylesheet loading is delayed by javascript loading, and CSS styles are not where the browser looks for them in the first place.

First, move all links to CSS stylesheets to the `<head>` of your page - right now they're in `<body>`. If this doesen't solve the issue, move all of your `<script>` tags from `<head>` to just before the closing `</body>` tag.